# Sharing instance variables between tests in Arquillian TestNG test methods in one class

Tags: testng, jboss-arquillian

Disclaimer: *I know this is a very bad design to actually have tests depend on each other to set any kind of variables. However I have to migrate these tests to Arquillian and rewriting everything is out of question.*

---

Question: I have test methods that use some instance variables like this:

```
public int myNumber= 0;

@Test
public void testOne() {
// do something with myNumber
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "testOne")
public void testTwo {
// do something with myNumber
```

This used to work using the jboss microcontainer. But it doesn't, while running such test in-container using Arquillian. What is the easiest way to make this work again? Right now I simply made all the fields static, which works. Are there any negative consequences of that?

---

Edit: Cedric's suggestion doesn't work neither, which is probably due to the same reason instance variables don't work. Arquillian invokes the whole lifecycle for each `@Test` method and it looks like it injects a new `ITestContext` to each `@Test` as well. This is what I tried:

```
Integer number = new Integer(10);
static final String NUMBER = "number";

@Test(dataProvider = Arquillian.ARQUILLIAN_DATA_PROVIDER)
public void testOne(ITestContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("TEST ONE: " + number);
    number += 100;
    ctx.setAttribute(NUMBER, number);
    System.out.println("CONTEXT " + ctx.getName());
    System.out.println("CONTEXT " + ctx.getAttribute(NUMBER));
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods="testOne", dataProvider = Arquillian.ARQUILLIAN_DATA_PROVIDER)
public void testTwo(ITestContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("TEST TWO: " + number);
    System.out.println("CONTEXT " + ctx.getName());
    System.out.println("CONTEXT " + ctx.getAttribute(NUMBER));
}
```

And result:

```
TEST ONE: 10
CONTEXT Arquillian - class com.example.ServerTest
CONTEXT 110
TEST TWO: 10
CONTEXT Arquillian - class com.example.ServerTest
CONTEXT null
```

Comment: It seems this is not possible, by design:  [http://jayshaughnessy.blogspot.com/2012/11/arquillian-and-testng.html](http://jayshaughnessy.blogspot.com/2012/11/arquillian-and-testng.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what caused it to stop running (it should work), but you could declare an `ITestContext` in the signature of both these methods, which will be injected by TestNG, and then call `setAttribute`/`getAttribute` to share parameters between your methods.

Comment: It was not clear from my question: I am running the test using Arquillian in-container in JBoss 7. Arquillian invokes the whole lifecycle including the @After/@Before methods for each @Test method inside the class.

Comment: I've added results after I tried your suggestion into my question. Unless I did something wrong, it doesn't work (as I expected knowing Arquillian architecture).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to share data between tests is to use a (CDI) managed bean.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyTestContext
{
    @Produces @ApplicationScoped
    Map<String, Object> objectStore()
    {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}

public class IntegrationTests extends ArquillianTest
{
    @Inject
    Map<String, Object> objectStore; 

    @Test() @InSequence(1)
    public void testReadAllUsers()
    {
        objectStore.put("x", 100);
    }

    @Test() @InSequence(2)
    public void testCreateNewUser() 
    {
        assertThat((Integer)objectStore.get("x")).isEqualTo(100);
    }
}
```